# Event-bound mass mailing platform

Tags: streaming, mailing-list

There are some [paid] bulk mailing platforms on the market like MailChimp etc. They all use the same way of working: users subscribe to a channel themselves and "forever" (until they unsubscribe themselves) and receive emails from me.

I need a mailing based on paid events and would like to have it in the following way:

- It's event-bound. I don't want people to be able to subscribe themselves. They all email me a request for a future event 1-7 days before with payment screenshot. I then have enough time to verify that their payment actually happened, and then I manually add their email addresses that they emailed from to the mailing list.
- Each time, a different mailing list is created with different participants, which must be filled from scratch.
- Usually there are 20-50 participants
- I schedule an unlisted stream on YouTube that is only available if one knows a direct URL.
- I send this URL to the participants around 10-30 minutes before the event.
- If the stream breaks, I start a new one, with a new URL, which I just distribute via the same event-bound mailing list. All participants should get the same mail at the same moment, so I don't spend 20-30 minutes sending mails.

Could you please recommend a mailing platform that meets the above criteria?

Sending emails by myself, manually or with an automation software installed on my PC is risky because email services could ban me.

Answer (score 1):

I have done just this with [Constant Contact](https://www.constantcontact.com). This service *can* work the way you described MailChimp, although you can also use it exactly the way you want to.

You can create a new mailing list, and add contacts to that list by entering details one-by-one, copy-pasting a list of emails or names + emails, or importing an Excel or CSV. Nobody can "subscribe themselves" unless you explicitly provide them with a link to do so in a specialized kind of email.

You can create emails and then choose which mailing list(s) to send the emails to. Emails can be sent on-demand (takes a minute or two until they all get sent out) or scheduled to be sent at a specific time.

Pricing is based on number of contacts, with up to 500 contacts being $9.99/month. Everyone you ever added to a mailing list is a "contact," but you can delete contacts if you no longer need them, so you probably wouldn't need more than 500. Additionally, there is a 60-day free trial for which you **don't** need to give a credit card number.